# Ganache-cli server and Webjs not connecting

Tags: javascript, web3js, ganache

I am trying to connect web3js in the javascript section of my html to my ganache-cli nodejs server

ganache deployment script:

```
const ganache = require("ganache-cli");
const Web3 = require("web3");
const web3 = new Web3(ganache.provider());

const { interface, bytecode } = require("./compile");

const deploy = async () => {
  const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();

  const result = await new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(interface))
    .deploy({
      data: bytecode,
      arguments: ["test"],
    })
    .send({ from: accounts[0], gas: "1000000" });

  console.log(`Contract address: ${result.options.address}`);

};

var server = ganache.server();

server.listen(8545, function (err, blockchain) {
  console.log(server);
  console.log(" live at port 8545");
});

deploy();
```

my frontend html/js file

```
if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
            web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
        } else {
        web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://127.0.0.1:8545"));
      
        web3.eth.defaultAccount = web3.eth.accounts[0];
        var info = new web3.eth.Contract(
           JSON.parse(interface), '0xeD9a9f326F38223a6599309F7201562DfB177997');
        
        
        console.log(info.methods.GetInfo("test").call());

    }
```

But I get the following error:

```
index.js:297 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Returned values aren't valid, did it run Out of Gas? You might also see this error if you are not using the correct ABI for the contract you are retrieving data from, requesting data from a block number that does not exist, or querying a node which is not fully synced.
```

solidty code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;

contract DVA {
   struct Info {
        // uint Age;
        // bool AgeRestriction;

        string DO_Num;
        string date;
        string time;
        string status;
        string otherstatus;

        string imagehash;
        string imagename;

    }
    mapping (string => Info[]) AllInfo;

    function SetInfo(string _DO, string _date, string _time, string _status, string _otherstatus, string _imagehash, string _imagename) public {

         Info memory info = Info(_DO,_date,_time,_status,_otherstatus,_imagehash,_imagename); 
      
        AllInfo[_DO].push(info);
      
       }
  

   function GetInfo(string _DO) public view returns (string memory) {
        // return (AllInfo[_DO].status,AllInfo[_DO].time);
                return "hi";

    }   
}
```

The code above is the contract code.
The weird thing is, I can call SetInfo but not GetInfo. I have ensured the contract address is valid, and that the ABI is correct as well. In fact, the ABI is retrieved directly upon each compilation of the solidty code as well.

Comment: Please edit the question and share the contract source code and the ABI (that you redacted by the `...`). Your JS snippet is trying to call the `GetInfo(string)` contract function but it's possible that it's either not defined in the contract source or the ABI, not visible in the context, failing due to a `require()` condition, etc... Also, please verify if the contract is deployed on the `0xD9a9...` address on your local environment.

Comment: @PetrHejda I have updated the post, thank you. I have ensured that the contract exists at the address. I also tried aclling the SetInfo() function and it works with no issue, only GetInfo() is failing.